# ImportError ropevim using ropevim plugin in vim

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin

According to the documentation of [rope-vim plugin](https://github.com/python-rope/ropevim) I install python-rope and python-ropemode mode packages. However when I try to open some file using vim I get following ImportError:

```
 Error detected while processing function LoadRope:
 line    4:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 ImportError: No module named ropevim
```

I have found the ropevim module is already in plugin's directory but when I had tried to import it:

```
python -c "import ropevim"
```

I get another ImportError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "ropevim.py", line 10, in <module>
  import vim
ImportError: No module named vim
```

Have I miss any package? Some ideas? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it might not be the answer you're looking for, but I'm using [klen/python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode) plugin with rope included and it's working like a charm.

I'm also using [Vim-Plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) to manage my plugins and it's as easy as:

```
Plug 'klen/python-mode', { 'for': ['python'] }
```

Here is my [`.vimrc`](https://github.com/ladislas/nvim/blob/master/vimrc#L314)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: `klen/python-mode` seems to not redirect to `python-mode/python-mode`.  It may be worth updating to the newest version of the link.

Comment: The recommended `vim-plug` syntax for `python-mode` is now: `Plug 'python-mode/python-mode', { 'for': 'python', 'branch': 'develop' }`, i.e., they recommend using the `develop` branch.

Answer (score 7):

Install ropevim using `pip install ropevim`

Answer (score 1):

`ropevim` is [currently a Python 2 project](https://github.com/python-rope/ropevim/issues/63).

```
pip2 install --user --update ropevim
```

Comment: While this post was correct at the time, Python 2 is no longer support with `ropevim`.  It is exclusively a Python3 project per the [project README](https://github.com/python-rope/ropevim/blob/master/README.rst).